# Install4j Linux installer not working

Tags: linux, install4j

I made installers for my application, it works on Windows and Mac, but when I try to run the .sh installer file on linux, it fails with this error:

> gzip: sfx_archive.tar.gz: not in gzip format
>
> I am sorry, but the installer file seems to be corrupted. If you downloaded that file please try it again. If you transfer that file with ftp please make sure that you are using binary mode.

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: @arkascha Totally besides the point, this question is about a multi-platform installer and you are obviously not familiar with this tool. You can write a blog post somewhere if you want to give a general lecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message describes the probable reason:

> I am sorry, but the installer file seems to be corrupted. If you 
>   downloaded that file please try it again. If you transfer that file with 
>   ftp please make sure that you are using binary mode.

You probably transferred it to the Linux machine in such a way that the line endings were replaced or the installer script was truncated.

Comment: That was it. I forgot to check the file was correct. It was transferred with ftp without using binary mode.

Answer (score 1):

This may be because you opened the file in a text viewer, which can change some aspects of the file. Try redownloading it and running it without opening it.

```
chmod +x install_file.sh 
./install_file.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the problem is that you're attempting to extract sfx_archive.tar.gz using tar with the z flag, and that it's not actually gzip compressed.

I would try substituting your current tar command with the following:

```
tar -xvf sfx_archive.tar.gz
```